# My facebook page for chatbot doesn't pass messages to webhook

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm having problem with my facebook page. 
I created a facebook page and connected it to webhook(Heroku) and published the page as well so it goes public.

[App review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwBg4.png)

When I, as the page admin, message the page, all the messages gets passed on to the webhook. But when somebody else messages it, messages just go to the page inbox and don't get passed to the webhook. I checked the log on heroku, they never reach the app.

I read facebook help page and other postings about facebook chatbot for days but I couldn't find the solution.. :(

Can anyone please shine a light on this?

Below are my app/page settings;

[fb page settings - messenger platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sghxA.png)

[App settings - basic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALwny.png)

[webhook subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lwsU.png)

[webhook settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BNzs.png)

Comment: Your last screenshot clearly shows that you still go messenger-related features to submit for review ...

Comment: Before submitting your app for review only your messages and of app Testers will be send to the server.

Comment: Review the Messenger submission guide. As @CBroe said, you haven't submitted for Messenger review:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review

Comment: thanks guys! I did find the submit button and did so a week ago but apparently FB isn't reviewing apps at the moment...

Comment: Same issue for me, I can message my page and my webhook capture them but the FB testers or other admins are not captured.